# UIKit: multiple dropdown in modal not showed properly

Tags: html, jquery, uikit

i've got this html into a modal that show 4 dropdown list (selectize)

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
   <div class="uk-form-row">                            
      <div class="parsley-row">
         <label for="CmbInk1" class="">Colore 1<span class="req">*</span></label>
         <input id="CmbInk1" type="text" class="md-input label-fixed " required>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[.....]

```
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
   <div class="uk-form-row">                            
      <div class="parsley-row">
         <label for="CmbInk4" class="">Colore 4<span class="req">*</span></label>
         <input id="CmbInk4" type="text" class="md-input label-fixed " required>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I see the situation
[image: dropdown not aligned verticaly]
(not aligned properly)
but if i resize page (for example) I can see all dropdown ok (like this ) [image: dropdown now aligned verticaly]
any suggest to fix it?
P.S. I fill all field from jquery, and I also call Modal from jquery.
Thanks a lot